# Php dynamic variable in $_POST wont hit

Tags: php, html, forms, dynamic, xhtml

I am ready to rip my hair out.

Basically I have to create a page which reads a directory of files and creates a form allowing you to press an Import button next to each files name to import the file into the database.

I scan through the directory like this:

```
$files=scandir('uploads');//get array of files/directories in uploads
foreach($files as $file) {//loop through the array
    if(!is_dir($file)) {//if not a directory must be a file
        echo $file.'<input type="submit" value="Import CSV File" name="'.$file.'" >';
    }
}
```

and than in the same form (an all in one form) I do:

```
$files=scandir('uploads');//get array of files/directories in uploads
foreach($files as $file) {//loop through the array
    if(!is_dir($file)) {//if not a directory must be a file
        if(isset($_POST[$file])) {//this if never hits 
            echo 'aa';
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

as you can see by my comments when I click a button to import a file the `if(isset($_POST[$file]))` never hits...

I have no idea why..

Here is some more code on the page for better overall understanding

import_csv.php:

```
<?php 
    if(session_id()=='') {
        session_start(); 
    }
    // check if user is not logged in thus is most likely not allowed to view the page or login went wrong
    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])||$_SESSION['loggedin']===false) {
        echo '<p>You are not logged in. Please <a href="index.php">login</a> and try again.</p>';
        exit();//stops the execution of the php file so we dont show the links below to unauthorized visitors
    }

    $files=scandir('uploads');//get array of files/directories in uploads
    foreach($files as $file) {//loop through the array
        if(!is_dir($file)) {//if not a directory must be a file
            if(isset($_POST[$file])) {
                echo 'aa';
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
?>

<h2 align="center">Import CSV Files:</h2>

<p align="center">
This will allow you to view names of uploaded CSV files and import them into the database.
Below are a list of available files on the server to be imported:
</p>

<form method="post" action="import_csv.php">

<?php

    //Create connection and suppress any errors for now using @
    $con=@mysqli_connect('localhost','jd','1111','my_db');

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo 'Could not connect to database.';
        exit();
    }else {
        //query all tables in db
        $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM my_db;";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


        //loop through results/all tables
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            if($row[0]=='users'&&isset($_SESSION['user_type']) && $_SESSION['user_type']!='admin') {
            }else {
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$row[0].'" > '.$row[0].'<br></br>';
            }
        }
    }

    $files=scandir('uploads');//get array of files/directories in uploads
    foreach($files as $file) {//loop through the array
        if(!is_dir($file)) {//if not a directory must be a file
            echo $file.'<input type="submit" value="Import CSV File" name="'.$file.'" >';
        }
    }
?>
</form>
```

Comment: the file name is a key in the $_POST array? wheres it posted from?

Comment: @Dagon what do you mean? inside the form tag is my php block which creates the buttons and text next to the button by scanning the directory. when a button is pressed the form will post to *import_csv.php* which is the same page (an all in one form) it will loop through the files again and check `if(isset($_POST[$file]))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the file Extension problem, file extension always should be '.', but php it converted to '_'. then Please rewrite your code like,

```
$files=scandir('uploads');//get array of files/directories in uploads
foreach($files as $file) {//loop through the array
    $postName   =   str_replace('.','_',$file);
        if(isset($_POST[$postName])) {//if not a directory must be a file
            echo 'aa';
            exit();
        }
    }
```

here the $file should like file.csv, but the PHP REQUEST array contains $_POST[file_csv]

Comment: Also my checkboxes wont hit in the post could it be the same problem?

Comment: Please print the entire $_POST or $_REQUEST array print_r($_POST), it will shows the parameters name